# Huge memory usage difference between lazy set and immediate set in make

Tags: makefile, variable-assignment

I have noticed that there is difference in memory usage between lazy set:

```
XML2_INC=$(shell echo `xml2-config --cflags`)
```

and immediate set:

```
XML2_INC:=$(shell echo `xml2-config --cflags`)
```

in makefile for simultaneous job when using:

```
make -j
```

Screen from system monitor:
[image]

in around 40th second in the timeline lazy set is being used and in around 15th second immediate set is being used. So my question is why there is such a big difference in memory consumption between those two?

Comment: Post a [mcve], you'll need to first show that this isn't due to something else you're doing in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

The first assignment is a lazy assignment and is evaluated each time it is used - so `xml2-config` will run each time you are using `XML2_INC` as variable. The second one is evaluated when defined.